# How to use formidable npm to upload files to Google Cloud

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, formidable

I tried to upload files to my Google Cloud bucket using formidable (using the example at https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable-serverless?activeTab=readme ) but still couldn't get it uploaded on my bucket.

This is my .env file

```
GCS_BUCKET = <bucket-name>
GCLOUD_PROJECT = <project-name>
GCS_KEYFILE = <key file location>
```

This is what I tried

```
const formidable = require('formidable-serverless');
const http = require('http');
const util = require('util');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  if (req.url == 'gs://<bucket-name>/' && req.method.toLowerCase() == 'post') {
    // parse a file upload
    const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
      res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
      res.write('received upload:\n\n');
      res.end(util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files}));
    });

    return;
  }

  // show a file upload form
  res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/html'});
  res.end(
    '<form action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">'+
    '<input type="text" name="title"><br>'+
    '<input type="file" name="upload" multiple="multiple"><br>'+
    '<input type="submit" value="Upload">'+
    '</form>'
  );
}).listen(8080);
```

I also tried Mutler (https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-google-storage) , can anyone help with working examples

Comment: Could you share the error it's giving when you try to upload to Cloud Storage?

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a late post.

Just not to keep the question unanswerable.

```
const express = require('express');
const formidable = require('formidable');
const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const bucket = 'yourBucketName';

async function uploadFile(bucket, filename) {
const storage = new Storage();
const params = { metadata: { cacheControl: 'public, max-age=31536000' } 
};
    await storage.bucket(bucket).upload(filename, params);
    console.log(`${filename} uploaded to ${bucket}.`);
}

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send(`
    <h2>With <code>"express"</code> npm package</h2>
    <form action="/api/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
      <div>Text field title: <input type="text" name="title" /></div>
      <div>File: <input type="file" name="someExpressFiles" multiple="multiple" /></div>
      <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form>
  `);
});

app.post('/api/upload', (req, res, next) => {
    const form = formidable();

    form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
        if (err) {
            next(err);
            return;
        }
        let imgPath = files.someExpressFiles.path;
        uploadFile(bucket, imgPath).catch(console.error);
        res.json({ fields, files });
    });
});

app.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log('Server listening on http://localhost:8080 ...');
});
```